# Give an example of a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto \mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Give an example of a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ having the property that for $a \in \mathbb R$ and $v \in \mathbb R^2$

$f(av) = af(v)$,

and $f$ is not a linear map.

Comment: Please, show what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 2):

What needs to break is **additivity**. Every polynomial is homogenous of degree equal to its degree. So let's take
$$ f(x,y) = \sqrt[3]{x^3 + y^3} $$

which is obviously not additive

Comment: "Every polynomial is homogenous of degree equal to its degree" -> but we need odd degree, to preserve the sign.